# Redirecting in the middle of a transaction is a normal thing?

Tags: php, pdo

Here is a transaction structure:

```
try {
    $dbh_con->beginTransaction();

    // queries here

    $dbh_con->commit();

} catch(PDOException $e) {

    $dbh_con->rollBack();

}
```

Now I want to know can I use `header('Location: ../);` in the transaction? So what happens?

Here is 3 cases:

```
try {
    $dbh_con->beginTransaction();

    header('Location: ../mypage.php1'); // (1)

    // queries here

    $dbh_con->commit();

    header('Location: ../mypage.php2'); // (2)

} catch(PDOException $e) {

    header('Location: ../mypage.php3'); // (3)

    $dbh_con->rollBack();

}
```

Ok using a redirect code in where of `(1)`, `(2)` and `(3)` is standard? And what happens with the queries in that case?

Based on the tests, when I redirect a script before `commit()` *(even after queries)*, none of those queries never work. I mean nothing changes.

Comment: It is not a normal thing. You would put `exit;` right after you set all headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirection doesn't occur as soon as you use `header()`.  The script continues to execute as normal.  The `header()` will only take effect when the first piece of content is sent to the browser.

If you've set the same header multiple times, only the latest will be sent to the browser (the earlier setting is overwritten).

```
header('Location: /a.php');
... do some work
header('Location: /b.php');
...
//one of the lines below will cause redirection to /b.php
echo "first piece of content!"; //<- send to the browser if buffering is off
ob_flush();// <- send contents to browser if buffering is on
```

Of course in your example, if there is an exception, the `catch` block header will take effect since it will be the last set `Location` header.

Setting the same header multiple times in your script makes it harder to debug. Set it in one place, once you have enough info to know where to send the user:

```
try {
    $dbh_con->beginTransaction();
    // queries here
    $dbh_con->commit();
    $uri = '/a.php';

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    $uri = '/b.php';
    $dbh_con->rollBack();

} finally {
    header("Location: $uri");
}
```

Comment: `echo`ing not necessary causes a flush.

Comment: I guess `finally` is what I was looking for .. thank you .. upvote

Comment: @stack but I personally highly suggest to not follow the first sample from the answer: it is always easier to maintain code that stops right after all headers are set and that does not overrwrite headers.